# How do i style the form inside grapesjs?

Tags: grapesjs

There is already a form component in grapesjs which comes from grapesjs-plugin-forms. But I don't see any way to style the form. I want to style the form with predefined CSS. It will be of great help if you can provide any tips. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You've to load external style-sheet to modify the form.
like this in the plugin setting

```
canavs: {
  styles: [...cdnlink],
}
```